# changing the method in `recommenderlab` in R

Tags: r

I'm using library("recommenderlab") and want to create a recommender model using "*user based collaborative filtering (UBCF)*". The default similarity measure for this is **cosine** but I'd like to change it to **pearson**. Here is my code excerpt

```
## create a matrix with ratings
m <- matrix(sample(c(as.numeric(0:5), NA), 50,  
+   replace=TRUE, prob=c(rep(.4/6,6),.6)), ncol=10,  
+   dimnames=list(user=paste("u", 1:5, sep=''),  
+   item=paste("i", 1:10, sep=''))) 

## coerce into a realRatingMAtrix
r <- as(m, "realRatingMatrix")  

## Create a recommender using "UBCF" with default cosine similarity 
uu.rec=Recommender(r[1:5],method="UBCF")
```

Because the Recommender uses the registry mechanism (called "**recommenderRegistry**"), the default method can be found by:

```
getModel(uu.rec)$method
```

[1] "cosine"

So the question is how I can change this to "pearson" similarity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the third parameter of Recommender(), *parameter*, to pass the algorithm a.k.a. recommender method the dissimilarity metric you want to use:

```
uu.rec=Recommender(data=r[1:5], method="UBCF", param=list(normalize="Z-score", method="pearson", nn=50, minRating=3, sample=F)
```